# Unterschied zwischen "fällig" und "zahlbar"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, meaning

Ich habe vor kurzem angefangen, die deutsche Sprache zu lernen. Ich wohne in Russland. Meine ABBYY Lingvo Wörterbuchanwendung übersetzt *fällig* und *zahlbar*  als *подлежащий уплате* (auf Englisch *due* oder *payable*).

In meinem Lehrbuch habe ich darüber gelesen, dass es einen Unterschied gibt, aber es wurde nichts über den genauen Unterschied zwischen diesen deutschen Wörtern geschrieben.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*fällig* bedeutet, dass eine bestimmte Sache bis zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt erledigt sein muss bzw. sollte. Man kann es auch verwenden, um zu monieren, dass eine bestimmte Sache noch nicht erledigt wurde.
Man findet es insofern oft auf Rechnungen:

> Fällig am 21.11.2014 (die Rechnung muss bis zum 21.11.2014 bezahlt werden)

Es kann auch umgangssprachlich verwendet werden, um auszudrücken, dass jemand Ärger bekommen wird:

> Wenn ich Dich noch einmal auf meinem Grundstück erwische, bist Du fällig!

*zahlbar* kann, *in Bezug auf Rechnungen* ebenfalls verwendet werden:

> Zahlbar innerhalb von 14 Tagen.

Aber nicht für andere Aufgaben:

> *Deine Hausarbeit ist zahlbar.

Weiterhin kann es verwendet werden, wie etwas bezahlt werden kann:

> Zahlbar per Rechnung, Kreditkarte oder Nachnahme.

**English**

"fällig" means, that a certain task should be done to a certain date. It can also be used to remind that it should have been done. It is therefore often found on bills:

> Fällig am 21.11.2014 (bill is due to 21.11.2014)

It can be used in a colloquial sense to denote that someone is at risk:

> Wenn ich Dich noch einmal auf meinem Grundstück erwische, bist Du fällig! (If I catch you on my property again, I'll (do something nasty to you)

*zahlbar* can be used for bills as well:

> Zahlbar innerhalb von 14 Tagen.

But it cannot be used for other tasks:

> *Deine Hausarbeit ist zahlbar.

It can be used to describe how something can be paid:

> Zahlbar per Rechnung, Kreditkarte oder Nachnahme.